# I am Writing a code on Xml Attribute sometimes it's working sometimes it's not working

Tags: xml, vb.net

```
Dim objXMLElement As XmlNode = Nothing
Dim objXMLElement1 As XmlNode = Nothing
Dim objXMLAttribute As XmlAttribute = Nothing

objXMLElement1 = doc.CreateElement("Country")              
objXMLElement1.InnerText = "united kingdom"
objXMLAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Code")
objXMLAttribute.Value = "GBR"
objXMLElement1.Attributes.Append(objXMLAttribute)                
objXMLElement.AppendChild(objXMLElement1)
```

This element was not creating attribute values, it create only innertext how to solve this problem

Comment: This code wouldn't even run because the last line will throw a NullReferenceException. Where do you instanciate objXMLElement ?

Comment: Could you prepare separate sample values for the case "its working" and the case "its not working"?